# Trigger a jQuery DOM manipulation event through an EmberJS action

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-observable

I have a very trivial Ember APP in the making. For the sake of my own sanity, I prefer to do the necessary animations and simple dom events like mouseover/clicks through jQuery within EmberViews.

Let's say I have this:

```
App.SomeView = Ember.View.extend({

     didInsertElement:function(){
       this.$(element).hover(function(){
                 $(anotherElement).toggle();
       });
     }

});
```

My template is something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-template-name="routeName">
   {{#view SomeView}}
      <button {{action 'something' this}}>    </button>
      <element></element>
       {{#if condition}}
        <anotherElement></anotherElement> 
       {{/if}}
  {{/view}}
</script>
```

And my controller, accordingly supports the action 'something' like this:

```
App.SomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  condition:false,
  actions:{
    something:function(){
      this.set('condition',true);
    }
  }
});
```

Everything works great, but what I want the '**something**' action to do is to trigger the '**didInsertElement**' event in my view so that '**anotherElement'** visibility is toggled without me having to write down that code all over again.

Does this make any sense?  I tried using **'observables'** but could not get them to work.

ALternately, if there are better ways to doing this, those are welcome as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can define an action in your view that does what you want and specify the target for the action to be the view.

```
<button {{action 'something' target="view"}}></button>
```

And in your view,

```
App.SomeView = Ember.View.extend({
  ...

  actions: {
    'something': function() {
      // Do whatever you want.     
    }
  }
});
```